# Which WordPress hook fires after post content loaded?

Tags: posts, hooks, post-content

Is there any hook that fires after post contents load? before comments and ...
I need to add an element at the bottom of the post content.

Comment: You can add to the post content using the `post_content` filter. It’s thoroughly documented and there’s many articles if you need help.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Thank you so much, It Works.

Comment: can you post that solution as an answer below rather than a comment?